# Oracle 12c validate_conversion not giving right output

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table:

table1

```
c_nm     c_val
Date    70120903
Date    41751213
Date    80650408
```

When I run the following query:

```
select C_NM , C_VAL
from table1
where C_NM = 'Date' and validate_conversion(C_VAL as date,'yyyymmdd') = 1;
```

It gives me all as correct, whereas these are all wrong dates and cannot be converted to date.

Do I need to add a condition?

Comment: These all work as date constants when I try:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ceddf566aba6fabdf99cc97fb9bf0f2b.

Comment: Why do you think they are *wrong*?

Comment: Because they are way farther. 7012 is not a valid year. It is far in future. Do I need to add a condition saying that the year needs to be between 1900 to 2100?